No audio on my pc
on my PC, no audio is output even though it is recognised. the problem appeared suddenly. i have kubuntu. what can I do?
-if i use headphone the problem persist
-all type of volume 100%

Have you tried the test option in the settings dialogue?

Please [edit] your question and give us some context. First, what Ubuntu are you using? Then, what is your hardware? Is this a laptop? Desktop? What audio card? How are you testing? What is recognized?
